# Baking Diffuse with AO Node is creating messy texture image

Tags: texture-baking, baking, ambient-occlusion

This what the baked texture looks like with the AO Node contibuting to the Base Color.  (Yes, it's rather high poly, that's because I am baking a sculpt paint).
[image]